# Finding the number of bytes between input and the location of the return address in the stack

Tags: c, stack, buffer, buffer-overflow

Wanted to know how to find the number of bytes between input and the location of the return address in the stack when this code is run and the value set to the %esp register immediately before `showstack()` is called

```c
void showstack (int a, int b, int c) {
    char input [14];
    char x, y;
    int *ret, i;

    for (i=0; i < 10; i++)
        input[i] = i;

    ret = (int *)input;

    for (i = 18; i >= 0; i--)
        printf("%8X:%8X\n", &(ret[i]), ret[i]);
}

int main(void) {
    showstack (1,2,3);
}
```

This is the output of the program:

```
BFFFF3BE:   1B7E3
BFFFF3BA:94D30000
BFFFF3B6:       0
BFFFF3B2:     804
BFFFF3AE:84E0B7FC
BFFFF3AA:4FF40000
BFFFF3A6:   30000
BFFFF3A2:   20000
BFFFF39E:   10804
BFFFF39A:84DEBFFF
BFFFF396:F3B8B7E5
BFFFF392:3196FFFF
BFFFF38E:FFFF5259
BFFFF38A: 6000804
BFFFF386:9FF40908
BFFFF382: 7060504
BFFFF37E: 3020100
```

Comment: Compile to assembly code, and examine the result.

Comment: You should tell in your question what OS and compiler you use. See e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/bM49sfqnb

Comment: You should enable all compiler warnings and fix them. To display a pointer like `&(ret[i])` you should use format `%p` instead of `%8X`. By running your program in a debugger you might be able to see the values of registers and to check the addresses of variables.

Comment: It's very likely here that your parameters are passed in registers and not on the stack, but that totally depends on the ABI (OS/hardware/compiler/switches).

Comment: MIRTY, Add tag to the processor on interest.

Comment: `Wanted to know how to find`, `output of program`. Great. I see both parameters and array values - what ***is*** your question?